# AngularJS routing Server side support (NodeJS+express)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, angularjs-routing

I am using NodeJS + expressJS on server and AngularJS on client

AngularJS controller have the following routes:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
$routeProvider
 .when('/field1/:id', {
  controller: 'ctrl1',
  templateUrl: "/view/mainpages/field1.html"
})
 .when('/field2/:id', {
  controller: 'ctrl2',
  templateUrl: "/view/mainpages/field2.html"
})
........... many many 
.when('/', {
  controller: 'ctrl0',
  templateUrl: "/view/mainpages/index.html"
})
.otherwise({redirectTo : '/'});
```

NodeJS static:

```
app.all('/*', express.static(__dirname + '/client'));
```

How to make the server redirects all the static pages on their paths relative to the root, in the case when the call goes directly through this link.

example:
`server:3000/field1/23` must call `server:3000/client/index.html` 
and index must upload JS like `server:3000/js/cntr1.js`

Upd: I found a solution to the problem. But it looks ugly as a crutch

```
app.get('/field1/([0-9]+$)', function(req, res, next) { 
    req.url='/index.html';
    next();
 });
app.use('/field1', express.static(__dirname + '/client'));
```

Perhaps there is a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 1):

In expressjs, you can define the route using regular expression pattern matching. That means, anything under a specific set will always return the same page from the server side, and you will let angular decide what exactly to display or do which action.

Its not a great idea to redirect everything at / to same page as you need to manage your assets and they exist on the / part too , instead its a good idea to use a subdir which is easy to manage

Following snippet will redirect everything under the app path to the same page on server side

```
app.get('/app/*', function(req, res) {
  res.send('app_index');
})
```

if you do not want to be limited to one app dir, instead you have a number of different root level dirs, all of which need to point to the same page, you can do something like this

```
app.get('/(app|server|client|form|dashboard)/*', function(req, res) {
  res.send('app_index');
})
```

Comment: `app.get('/field/:name', function(req, res) {`
`var name = req.params.name;`
  `res.render('/' + name);`
`});`    but :name can be an ID.  I seach universal solution. I think it's pretty spread the word problem in the REST applications

Comment: In this your comment code, What do you want to do ? You want to like `http://server:3000/name` right ? But this page will include which view ?

Comment: Yes. I want `http://server:3000/name` when name = 'index.html' or 'controll.js'.... but it can be '23' (parameter of angular page) and then `http://server:3000/field/2` =`http://server:3000/field`=`http://server:3000/`

Comment: i look `app.get('/field/([0-9]+$)'` but it's not a nice solution. I will have a lot of options. And would not like to paint for each path.